# How to edit the size of inlineEditSupport tab to optimize it for a Lightning app (Salesforce1)?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, inlineeditsupport

I am developing a Lightning app for Salesforce1 based on a custom VF page I created. I have a huge problem with a field that I want to make editable at any time. I didn't find any alternative to the use of apex method inlineEditSupport at the moment, but it doesn't look to be optimized for Salesforce1 per se.

My question is: is there any alternative to the use of inlineEditSupport which could make me get to a better graphical result? Or is there anyway to customize the size of the popup edit window which opens after selecting the editable field? I am using embedded HTML and I saw there were only options linked to the use of Javascript, which I don't know very well.. My current code is the following:

```
<apex:page controller="Account_Controller_2" docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="true" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
     <apex:form id="theForm">
         <style>[...]</style>
            <table>         
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><apex:outputLabel value="Current Status"/></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!account.Last_Status__c}"> 
                            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="onclick" rendered="true" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit" />
                        </apex:outputField>
                    </td>
                 </table>
          </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help on this, 
Francesco